# postfix connection to the smtp server timed out

Tags: postfix

Please help me with this issue:
when sending emails with an email client like Thunderbird I have the error #1 as below. Some people who's trying to send me a message have the error #2. IP is not in any RBL and have good reputation. I can connect to the yahoo's mailserver with telnet and have no errors.

Error #1.

```
The message could not be sent because the connection to SMTP server mail.legacyplanningadvocates.com timed out.
```

Error #2.

```
<david@legacyplanningadvocates.com>: 0 Validating Sender: Error: command not recognized
```

Logs are clean but I have many such errors which I do not understand:

```
Jul 24 06:37:12 www dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshake
Jul 24 06:37:12 www dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
Jul 24 06:37:13 www postfix/smtpd[6575]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 24 06:37:13 www postfix/smtpd[6575]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jul 24 06:37:13 www postfix/smtpd[6575]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

update:

```
Jul 24 07:29:33 www postfix/smtpd[8784]: 023E838B30: client=www.triquetradevelopment.com[68.169.39.151]
Jul 24 07:29:34 www postfix/smtpd[8784]: lost connection after RCPT from www.triquetradevelopment.com[68.169.39.151]
Jul 24 07:29:34 www postfix/smtpd[8784]: disconnect from www.triquetradevelopment.com[68.169.39.151]
```

Here is the Postfix [config file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17184781/postfix.cnf). Domain is pointed to the server via the MX record only.

```
uname -a
Linux www 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are all error #2 messages dealing with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @user48838 Most of the 'lost connections' lines are from localhost but I see some other lines like the ones in my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the high occurrence of errors from what should be local connections as you have identified, you may want to take a closer look at the processes and overall system processing load.

Comment: There is no load on the server. Uptime shows 0.01% and netstat shows 137 total connections.

Comment: Has the processes been restarted as part of the troubleshooting/determination efforts thus far?

Comment: Sure, I restarted postfix and iptables with no success.

Comment: How about a system reboot? Otherwise you might want to take a closer look at either Postfix or the internal process that is connecting to it. How are manual telnet connections directly to Postfix?

Comment: I performed: telnet localhost 25 (and 465 then) and looks like everything to be ok. I cannot restart the server as I have limited sudo access.

Comment: BTW, when the sending fails, it does not fail immediately.  It starts to be sent, and a progress bar appears showing the progress of transferring the message to the server. The progress bar then halts at a seemingly random position (different for every failed message, but identical on each attempt of the same message) and after about 90 seconds I get the error.

It appears that Thunderbird is successfully making contact
with the server and the message begins to be sent, but the message never completes, or the server never communicates that sending has completed.

Comment: The local (127.0.0.1) failures are a primary indication that needs to be followed up on first. Its current existence trumps all external connection situations at this point in any systematic troubleshooting.

Comment: so what should I do now? )

Comment: Coordinate a reboot with the folks who can to continue the troubleshooting efforts. When was the last reboot?

Comment: Ok, reboot didn't help.

Comment: I have found an smtp proxy server sitting on the port 465 and filtering connections. I have disabled it and everything is working now fine.

Comment: Good deal. It looks like going through the troubleshooting helped identify things.